# Stuck drum brake

Tags: drum-brakes

I have seen many videos and online tutorials for disassembling a drum brake, but they all look different. The ones I see online have the bolts emerging from the rim where the drum slides as the picture:
[image]
However, on my car(Peugeot 301), the drum looks a bit different as shown in the picture:
[image]

I can’t seem to remove the drum no matter what I do, keeping in mind that it rotates freely and isn’t stuck in place by the brakes. So, does this type have a different way of removal, by bolts or something? Or does this center cap need to be removed first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the center cap, the drum is held on by a castle nut and there's a bearing in there as well. Pop the cap off and you should be able to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: This makes more sense now. Thank you for the reply! Any idea about how to remove it though? Seems very rusty and stuck

Comment: Or maybe any online videos showing how? What should i search for to find this type?

Comment: @user3407319. This one is similar - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cSfx1PBpGm0

Comment: I have a dedicated wood chisel for hammering into tight gaps. You canalso use a sharpened flat screwdriver. Once it is up a bit use a pry tool.

Comment: A few shots of penetrating fluid should help.